# On sending message using JSQmessage Lib i get following exception "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[Updated full image of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQOJU.png)   [Image shows the console containing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGrBj.png)Xcode throws this exception when send button is pressed on message view controller toolbar.

```
DataManager* dm = [DataManager sharedInstance];

NSDictionary* msgdata = @{KChatIdentifier: _chatId,
                          kMessageToIdentifier : _toIdentifier,
                          kMessageFromIdentifier : _fromIdentifier,
                          kMessageText : text,
                          kMessageType : [NSNumber numberWithInt:MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT],
                          kMessageSenderName: dm.currentUser.username,
                          kMessageSenderImageURL: dm.currentUser.imageURL,
                          kMessageReceiverName: @"", kMessageReceiverImageURL:@""};

NSLog(@"%@", msgdata);


[[SocketManager sharedInstance] sendText:msgdata];

JSQMessage* newMessage = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:self.senderId displayName:self.senderDisplayName text:text];
[_arrMessages addObject:newMessage];
[self checkForDateHeader:date index:_arrMessages.count-1];

[self finishSendingMessage];
```

}

Comment: There should be more text about the NSException.

Comment: No i have attached the console picture, i am attaching the full image of console please take a look

Comment: Try to click on "Continue"? Usually, there is more info, "reason: " after your message.

Comment: There is nothing even after continue.